# Why does PrintStream.close() end up getting called twice?

Tags: java, inheritance, printstream

Somewhat to my surprise, the following code prints out "Close" twice. Running through the debugger, it seems `MyPrintStream.close()` calls `super.close()`, which ends up calling `MyPrintStream.close()` again.

```
    
import java.io.*;

public class PrintTest
{
    static class MyPrintStream extends PrintStream
    {
        MyPrintStream(OutputStream os)
        {
            super(os);
        }

        @Override
        public void close()
        {
            System.out.println("Close");
            super.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        PrintStream ps = new MyPrintStream(new FileOutputStream(File.createTempFile("temp", "file")));
        ps.println("Hello");
        ps.close();
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? Should I not be extending PrintStream?

Comment: This something a debugger is good for. Place a breakpoint in the close method and you should be able to see why it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at PrintStream's source.

It has two references to the underlying Writer `textOut` and `charOut`, one character-base, and one text-based (whatever that means). Also, it inherits a third reference to the byte-based OutputStream, called `out`.

```
/**
 * Track both the text- and character-output streams, so that their buffers
 * can be flushed without flushing the entire stream.
 */
private BufferedWriter textOut;
private OutputStreamWriter charOut;
```

In the `close()` method it closes all of them (`textOut` is basically the same as `charOut`).

```
 private boolean closing = false; /* To avoid recursive closing */

/**
 * Close the stream.  This is done by flushing the stream and then closing
 * the underlying output stream.
 *
 * @see        java.io.OutputStream#close()
 */
public void close() {
synchronized (this) {
    if (! closing) {
    closing = true;
    try {
        textOut.close();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
    textOut = null;
    charOut = null;
    out = null;
    }
}
}
```

Now, the interesting part is that charOut contains a (wrapped) referenced to the PrintStream itself (note the `init(new OutputStreamWriter(this))` in the constructor )

```
private void init(OutputStreamWriter osw) {
   this.charOut = osw;
   this.textOut = new BufferedWriter(osw);
}

/**
 * Create a new print stream.
 *
 * @param  out        The output stream to which values and objects will be
 *                    printed
 * @param  autoFlush  A boolean; if true, the output buffer will be flushed
 *                    whenever a byte array is written, one of the
 *                    <code>println</code> methods is invoked, or a newline
 *                    character or byte (<code>'\n'</code>) is written
 *
 * @see java.io.PrintWriter#PrintWriter(java.io.OutputStream, boolean)
 */
public PrintStream(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush) {
this(autoFlush, out);
init(new OutputStreamWriter(this));
}
```

So, the call to `close()` will call `charOut.close()`, which in turn calls the original `close()` again, which is why we have the closing flag to cut short the infinite recursion.

Answer (score 11):

If you look at your code in a debugger and set a breakpoint in the `close()` method, it'll reveal the stacktraces of *who* is calling your `close()` method:

1. your main method
2. sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder$CharsetSE.implClose() line 431

the complete stacktrace for the latter looks like:

```
PrintTest$MyPrintStream.close() line: 20    
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder$CharsetSE.implClose() line: 431 [local variables unavailable]  
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder$CharsetSE(sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder).close() line: 160 [local variables unavailable]    
java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close() line: 222 [local variables unavailable]  
java.io.BufferedWriter.close() line: 250 [local variables unavailable]  
PrintTest$MyPrintStream(java.io.PrintStream).close() line: 307  
PrintTest$MyPrintStream.close() line: 20    
PrintTest.main(java.lang.String[]) line: 27
```

Sadly though I can't tell *why* StreamEncoder would call back into your PrintStream though, as my IDE doesn't have a source attachment for sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder :( This is JDK 6 btw, if that matters.

**By the way**, if you are asking this question because you noticed that custom code in your `close()` method is running twice, you should really be checking if `this.closing`. `PrintStream.close()` sets this to true (and the class's comments state `/* To avoid recursive closing */` ).

Comment: +1 for educating the user how to solve this by himself in the future

Comment: The 'closing' instance variable is private to PrintStream, so I can't check it, though of course I can use my own.

Comment: There are a couple of classes in the jdk which do something similar.  I believe it is because there are situations where classes A and B reference each other, and the user may have a reference to either A or B, and closing either of them should close the other.  

As mentioned, you should generally protect your close methods from multiple invocations (although recursive invocation is a more insidious and less expected situation).

Comment: Great answer.  simonn - I think the suggestion was to add your own closing instance variable if you need it.